# Download blocked attachment in outlook web

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, blocking, attachments, bypass

I'm currently in this scenario where I have been sent a one-off email containing a batch file no larger than 100kb. Clicking on the file does nothing, and there is no download href to view. I know it's safe since I trust the sender on that and even then I know to read the code before executing the file.

All the solutions I have found online so far are to use regedit to change a registry key (if you have the application) or to convince the sender the change/remove the file extension or upload it somewhere else. But you see, I cannot download the microsoft mail application and I must use their outlook.live.com website, and that email with the attachment I received will be the only one of its kind.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say, it's a one-off, here s one way to do it.

1. Create a new Google Account, they are free
2. Forward the email to this account
3. Open in Google Mail (GMail) and save it to your computer.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I never thought of that. But at the same time this solution was never even brought up once when I spent hours and hours searching for it online. Thanks mate.